# Hi all, I want to transpose my data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose, data-processing

```
data={'id':[1, 2, 3],'A': ['edx',None , 'edx'],'B': [None,'com',None ],'C': ['tab','tab',None ] }  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Given data frame :

```
id  A   B   C
1   edx None    tab
2   None    com tab
3   edx None    None
```

Desired Result:

```
id  Learn
1   edx
1   tab
2   com
2   tab
3   edx
```

Same I Expect that I have mentioned above.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Just as a point of reference, this is _not_ a traditional transpose, which turns the columns into rows and the rows into columns. This is a more complicated scenario than a transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  I would really suggest getting familiar with `pd.melt` as it's extremely useful in reshaping data that looks like this.

```
df = (df.melt(id_vars='id', value_name='Learn')
        .dropna()
        .sort_values(by='id', ascending='True'))
    
df.drop(columns=['variable'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output

```
   id Learn
0   1   edx
6   1   tab
4   2   com
7   2   tab
2   3   edx
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chris for the quick response !

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it. using stack

```
out=(df.set_index('id')     # set index
     .stack()               # stack
     .droplevel(1)          # remove the unwanted level
     .reset_index()
     .rename(columns={0:'Learn'}))
out
```

```
    id  Learn
0   1   edx
1   1   tab
2   2   com
3   2   tab
4   3   edx
```

Comment: Congrats on the 10k!